# How to predict rank in ordinal regression using R?

Tags: r, regression, ordinal-data, prediction

I have done an ordinal regression using `lrm` from the `rms` package.

```
load(url("http://www.produnis.de/R/NEXT-Q0-OR.RData"))
require(rms)
mydata <- NEXT.or
fit <- lrm(QuitJob~QD,data=mydata);fit
```

I would like to predict the rank in "QuitJob" (1=won't quit ... 5=will quit very soon) by giving a value for "QD" (how much work to do). For example, if "QD" is 78, what rank of "QuitJob" is likely?

If I type in

```
predict.lrm(fit, data.frame(QD=78))
```

I get

```
        1 
0.3191933
```

Do I understand it right, that the probability of being in rank 1 is 31,92% ?!
If so, how can I get the probabilities for ranks 2-5 ?

Comment: `predict(fit, data.frame(QD=78), type="fitted.ind")` gives predicted class probabilities, what you got is the value of the linear predictor, see [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/41025/1909).

Comment: thx, caracal... If you post your commend as an answer, I would mark it as "accepted"